# Html canvas video streaming

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have this code which playing my camera's view in a video tag and then into canvas element at the same page, the page has 2 squares one for the video tag(playing camera's view) and the other is for canvas(playing the same video of the video tag). How I can edit my code to make the video play in a canvas at another page to let my user watch it live, and if there is a method to let users watch it at the same page not another page and see the canvas only, it's also accepted.

here is my html file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>With canvas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="booth">
            <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay></video>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script src="video.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my js file:

```js
(function() {
    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    video = document.getElementById('video'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia ({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    }, function(stream) {
        //video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        if ('srcObject' in video) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
          } else {
            video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
          }
        video.play();
    }, function(error) {
        // An error occured
        //error.code
    });


    video.addEventListener('play', function() {
        setInterval(() => {
        draw(this, context, 400, 300);
        }, 100);

    }, false );
    function draw(video, context, width, height) {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
    
}) ();
```

Comment: if you wanted to play on another page you can get camera data as array buffer but why you wanted to play in canvas when you can play in video tag ?

Comment: will users be able to watch it live ? @Amir Rahman

Comment: you will get buffers in chunk which you have to send to other user in anyway then it can be played like live wait i have a code for this type of experiment i will be posting it in answer wait a min

Comment: Ok, @Amir Rahman

Answer (score 2):

use `MediaRecorder` to get live data in chunks as media recorder records from camera and give chunks that can be send over other end of user

then use `mediasource` to append chunks on other side of user to append it and play it live as it recieves new chunks

i know its a complicated thing but believe me when i was experimenting this i have  spent good amount of time to understand i believe you will get some benefit from my experiment code below

here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/cmLnp6sz/7/)

```
var mediasource = new MediaSource(),video = document.querySelector("video"),
    mime = 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediasource)

mediasource.addEventListener("sourceopen",function(_){
    var source = mediasource.addSourceBuffer(mime)
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true,audio: true}).then(stream=>{
        var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,{mimeType:mime})
        recorder.ondataavailable = d =>{
// creating chunks of 5 seconds of video continiously
            var r = new Response(d.data).arrayBuffer() // convert blob to arraybuffer
            r.then(arraybuffer=>{
                source.appendBuffer(arraybuffer)
            })
        }
        recorder.start(5000)
    })
})
```

```html
<video class="video" controls autoplay></video>
```

**separated version for gathering live data and playing it** [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/nd41m8co/)

```
// gathering camera data to liveData array
var vid = document.querySelector(".video"),
    mime = 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus',
    liveData = []

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true}).then(stream=>{
        var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,{mimeType:mime})
        recorder.ondataavailable = d =>{
            console.log("capturing")
            new Response(d.data).arrayBuffer().then(eachChunk=>{
            // recording in chunks here and saving it to liveData array                
                liveData.push(eachChunk)
            })
        }
        recorder.start(5000)    
    })
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
// playing from liveData in video 
var ms = new MediaSource()
vid.src =URL.createObjectURL(ms)

ms.onsourceopen = function(){
    var source = ms.addSourceBuffer(mime),chunkIndex = 0
    setInterval(function(){
        if(liveData.length > 0){
            var currentChunk = liveData[chunkIndex]
            source.appendBuffer(currentChunk)
            console.log("playing")
            chunkIndex++     
        }
    },5000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but how I shall let users watch it ? I want to let users watch it live like it happening at Facebook live for example but more simple.

Comment: this code is giving you 5 seconds of recording each time which can be played in video player with `MediaSource` since you cannot append chunks manually thats why `MediaSource` is here once you connect MediaSource to video player then append chunks in `MediaSource` it will append and play live

Comment: Sorry bro, Can you explain with code, please ? I didn't use this before so it's not clear for me, please help me. @Amir Rahman

Comment: ok firstly i will show you only recorder i know mediasource  API is not so user friendly but this is how it is

Comment: You are saving my life !

Comment: i will be posting another code which will describe part by part within 1 or 2 hour

Comment: all right @Amir Rahman

Comment: I don't know how I thank you, I liked you man, finally, how will users access and watch it ?, if they opened the same url the page will open their camera and show their own camera video, then how can  user watch it ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Tebai i have separated capturing and playing part with arrayBuffer now take a look at and try experiment

Comment: `liveData` is the data all you need to play wherever you want now its upto you how you send it to other end either with websocket or RTCpeerconnection

Comment: also i forgot to mention the first chunk is very important it has all the metadata that requires to play chunks then simply send new chunks to other end and append it to its `mediasource`

Comment: Thanks man, I really respect you

Comment: i will be happy if this help you achive what you are trying